# Apex trigger Causing issue

Tags: apex, trigger

I wrote an Apex trigger and when I try to delete a record then its giving me the following error.
"There's a problem saving this record. You might not have permission to edit it, or it might have been deleted or archived. Contact your administrator for help."

My Trigger is as follows.

```
    trigger ContactCount on hed__Relationship__c  (after insert, after update, after delete) {
    Map<Id, List<hed__Relationship__c >> AcctContactList = new Map<Id, List<hed__Relationship__c >>();
    Set<Id> AcctIds = new Set<Id>();    

    List<Contact> AcctList = new List<Contact>();
    List<hed__Relationship__c> ConList = new List<hed__Relationship__c>();

    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUPdate) {
        for(hed__Relationship__c Con : trigger.New) {
            if(String.isNotBlank(Con.hed__Contact__c)){
                AcctIds.add(Con.hed__Contact__c);  
            }   
        }  
    }

    if(trigger.isDelete || trigger.isUPdate) {
        for(hed__Relationship__c Con : trigger.Old) {
            AcctIds.add(Con.hed__Contact__c);     
        }  
    }           

    if(AcctIds.size() > 0){
        ConList = [SELECT Id, hed__Contact__c FROM hed__Relationship__c WHERE hed__Contact__c IN : AcctIds];

        for(hed__Relationship__c Con : ConList) {
            if(!AcctContactList.containsKey(Con.hed__Contact__c)){
                AcctContactList.put(Con.hed__Contact__c, new List<hed__Relationship__c>());
            }
            AcctContactList.get(Con.hed__Contact__c).add(Con);      
        }                           

        System.debug('Account Id and Contact List Map is ' + AcctContactList);

        AcctList = [SELECT Number_Of_Dependents__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN : AcctIds];

        for(Contact Acc : AcctList) {
            List<hed__Relationship__c> ContList = new List<hed__Relationship__c>();
            ContList = AcctContactList.get(Acc.Id);
            Acc.Number_Of_Dependents__c= ContList.size();
        }    

        System.debug('Account List is ' + AcctList);
        update AcctList;    
    }

}
```

Comment: I have  a feeling that given error has nothing to do with given trigger. Can you try to disable that trigger and check if issue still occurs?

Comment: make this trigger lightweight, put all processing logic in TriggerHandler type of class. Also, check that if person has a permission to perform certain operation

Comment: Hello Kurunve, If I disable the trigger then I am able to perform delete operation but if this trigger is active then I am getting the issue.

Comment: are you a System Administrator and has Modify All permission on Contact object?

Comment: I am the Admin and have all the permissions to both objects, if I disable the trigger then I can perform delete operation but if I make trigger as active then I am getting the issue over here.

Comment: Are there any triggers or so on Account? can you try to manually (or by dev console) to update Number_Of_Dependents__c on single account record?